# merge array to become simple array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

it is possible combine this array like image [image]
to become like this `[47,85]`

**Component**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.commonService.indexKey$.subscribe(e =>{
      console.log(e);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use map function on array like :-

```
const newData = e.map((data)=>data.id);
```